# powerbi api always returns NotFound

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using [powerbiapi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api/) to make calls directly to powerbi.  I have authenticated successfully and can successfully make a call to get all the datasets

```
var datasets = await _powerBiClient.Datasets.GetDatasetsAsync(_config.GroupId);
```

which returns all the datasets the user I authenticated with can access.

But when I make any other calls away from the one listed above i get a `NotFound` exception.

```
var d = await _powerBiClient.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdAsync(_config.GroupId,datasetKey);
```

or

```
var d = await _powerBiClient.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdAsync(datasetKey);
```

or

```
var r = await _powerBiClient.Datasets.PostRowsAsync(_config.GroupId,getIdResult.Result, tableName,rows);
```

I even tried to go around the api and make the call directly via webrequest

```
string powerBIApiAddRowsUrl = String.Format("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{0}/tables/{1}/rows", getIdResult, tableName);

//POST web request to add rows.
//To add rows to a dataset in a group, use the Groups uri: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/tables/{table_name}/rows
//Change request method to "POST"
HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(powerBIApiAddRowsUrl) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

that threw the `NotFound` exception also.

Looking at the [PowerBi Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasetbyid#dataset) I was orignally passing in the datasetKey as the name of the dataset (i.e. "DatasetSample")  I switched to passing in the Id, as the url examples in the documentation do and I still get a `NotFound`.

Can somebody give me insight into what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

NotFound means that the dataset you provided doesn't exist in the Group you provided.
DatasetId and GroupId both should be GUIDs. You can get the dataset ids and the group ids using GET requests or _powerBIClient you have.

```
GET /v1.0/myorg/groups

GET /v1.0/myorg/groups/<group id>/datasets

GET /v1.0/myorg/groups/<group id>/datasets/<dataset id>

using powerBIClient:
powerBIClient.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdAsync(groupId, datasetId)
```

Please note that the API is different if your dataset is in "My Workspace". for such case, the API is:

```
GET /v1.0/myorg/datasets

GET /v1.0/myorg/datasets/<dataset Id>

using powerBIClient:
powerBIClient.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdAsync(datasetId)
```

For validation, you can always extract the Group ID and the Dataset Id using URL in powerbi.com. just try to create a report from a dataset and look into the browser URL.

If the above doesn't work for you, use _powerBIClient, open fiddler and capture the outgoing request, and paste it here (without Authorization header of course).